# parsing Json is giving error in Java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse `json` string and get parameters. But its giving an error:
Please help me to solve this problem. I know there are many questions and answers for parsing `json` but this time its not working...

This is my code:
(*I'm receiving json in this format*)

```
//using this library
import org.primefaces.json.JSONArray;
import org.primefaces.json.JSONException;
import org.primefaces.json.JSONObject;

//this is how im receiving string - exactly same
String  jString =  "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t{"msg":"directPaidout is true, but paidout password is wrong","sts":"2"}";


//replacing \t with ""
jString = jString .replace("\t", "");

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jString);
String mString = jsonObject.getString("msg");
```

I'm getting this error:

```
org.primefaces.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1
```

**This is my full code:**

```
try {
     String jString = doPost(toUrl, params);
//Getting this string: 
// \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t{"msg":"directPaidout is true, but paidout password is wrong","sts":"2"}
     //replacing \t with ""
     jString = jString .replace("\t", "");

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jString);
    String mString = jsonObject.getString("msg");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: SEND: Exception in sending request!);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

//This is post and get String method
    public static String doPost(String url, String param) {
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String result = "";
        try {
            URL realUrl = new URL(url);

            URLConnection conn = realUrl.openConnection();

            conn.setRequestProperty("accept", "*/*");
            conn.setRequestProperty("connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1;SV1)");

            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            out = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

            out.print(param);

            out.flush();

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }
            //System.out.println("Res:" + result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("POST EXc！" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            try {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
                if (in != null) {
                    in.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: what is unclear in error message you are getting?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski its given at the end of question

Comment: that is not a string

Comment: Yes it is. Read it with understanding.

Comment: Well your code doesn't even compile. Please post correct code.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski My compiler is lacking the understanding plugin

Comment: I don't know what you were doing with `jstring`--were you just trying to show us what the value is, without writing it as a legal Java statement?  That makes it hard to tell whether your string begins with a space character.

Comment: @ajb I'm trying to show the exact string which Im receiving...

Comment: Please post the proper code ..

Comment: Just print out the String that you are getting and POST it here

Comment: @ScaryWombat Please take a look, i have updated my codes

Comment: fine, but you did not give me what I wanted

Comment: @ScaryWombat this is what im receiving: 
String result = "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t{"msg":"directPaidout is true, but paidout password is wrong","sts":"2"}";

Answer (score -2):

**This was the solution:**

```
if(jString .contains("{")){
jString = jString.substring(jString.indexOf("{")+0);
}
```

replace("\t", ""); was adding space between {

**Thanks for your support! I really appreciate it!**

Comment: In that case the json string was not as you said

Answer (score -3):

Please have a look and try if this code can help you. Your string object doesn't compile. One must escape the quotation marks like this: `\"` otherwise it won't compile.

```
import org.primefaces.json.JSONObject;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jString = "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t{\"msg\":\"directPaidout is true, but paidout password is wrong\",\"sts\":\"2\"}";
        jString = jString.replace("\t", "");
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jString);
        String mString = jsonObject.getString("msg");
        System.out.println(mString);
    }
}
```

Output

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -javaagent:/opt/idea-IU-171.3780.107/lib/idea_rt.jar=40176:/opt/idea-IU-171.3780.107/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/icedtea-sound.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/developer/IdeaProjects/sortarray/out/production/sortarray:/home/developer/Downloads/primefaces-6.1.jar Main
directPaidout is true, but paidout password is wrong

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Obviously, he wrote code that did compile, or else he wouldn't have gotten the error he got.  The way he asked the question was confusing, but he did not make the error that you're trying to fix.

Comment: The problem if I define string as your example It will work, but the string Im receiving is working until parsing it with json library

Comment: @Abdulin First the code must compile. If you post the code that compiles and gives the error then we can help you better.

Comment: @Abdulin How does the code look when you receive the string?